# Database to use when creating an installer for your c# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, installation

I am creating a c# application which requires to use a database and i am also planning to create an installer for my application. I just want to ask which database would be best to use in my application and how do i install it on a user machine while installing my application through installer file.
I have thought of using MYSQL database but for that u need to have MYSQL installed.

### Update

i want each user to have there own instance of database when they install the application

Comment: SQL CE would be pretty easy.

Comment: @BartTeunissen......don't you need to install it on user's system also

Comment: If you build a release, a dll of Sql CE will sufice. You can set these dll's to be build in the installer in your settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to ship a full database server with your application; only the redistributable runtime which your application would use to connect to the actual database server remotely.  In the case of MySQL, you only need the assemblies.

Applications I wrote relied heavily on SQL Server. In order to simplify evaluations and the initial deployment, the installer would install SQL Server Express (installed as an application specific instance).  This is an approach I'd recommend if your application is intended to a centralised database.

What is key to understand, especially with commercial application, is that the database engine you install may have to co-exist with existing versions of the respective database engine. That is why application specific instances was created for SQL Server Express.

The alternatives, which are embedded, are:

1. [SQLite.net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net)
2. [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx). The [deployment process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28VS.80%29.aspx) is well defined.
3. [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net)

Embedded databases have some challenges when deployed as part of a server application. For many years, Microsoft refused to allow [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) to be used for ASP.NET applications. If the database is per user, per device, an embedded database may be perfect.

Also be aware that MySQL has [license restrictions](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/) when shipped as part of commercial software (aka you're acting as an OEM, ISV or VAR).

Comment: i don't intend to create a centralized database.......i just want that when the user installs my application a database is created on his machine and all the tables are created there

Comment: Will every user that uses the workstation will use their own database, or share the database?

Comment: yeah every user who installs this application will have there own instance of database

Comment: Then I'd suggest looking for an embedded database that runs in-process. There are so many to pick from. I like SQLite or SQL Server compact edition. The have some limitations, but I haven't really encountered a problem for per user databases.  Installation is a breeze; just make sure the redistributable dlls are in the bin folder of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx).

It's just a file which you can copy and a class library which allows to access it. And after you finished your installation you can just delete the files (or to keep them if you need them to uninstall the product).

Comment: but i have read that SQL CE has many restrictions like db size and also u have to reindex your db when you run it on cross platform.

Comment: here a link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583278/sqlite-vs-sqlce-vs-in-a-mobile-application

Comment: Depends on how big your installation database is going to be. For SQL Server compact 4.0 max database size is 4 gb.

Answer (score 0):

may be u are a fresh.

MYSQL  is ok ,but u are creating a C# application,i strongly advise you use mssql 
because C# has a  close relationship with mssql,develop more convenient.

Comment: my question is whether while installing my application on some machine do i have to install the database also and if yes then how....please guide

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be using SQL Azure.

But only if:

- You don't need much storage (<1GB).
- You don't save sensitive Data there.
- Your users have an internet connection.

It's a cloud based Sql Server Database. And the Conneciton is very simple, basically you connect like to any other Database via the Connection String.

[www.windowsazure.com](http://www.windowsazure.com)

Comment: SQL Azure adds unnecessary overhead and cost for a per user per application database engine.